# Custom Controller action not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hoping someone can point out the error of my ways here. I've got a form with a custom action with a standard submit button:

```
= form_for( @property, :html => {:data => {:abide => ''}, :id  => 'property-edit-form'},:url => url_for(:action => 'update_promo')) do |f|
```

The route is as follows:

```
post 'properties/update_promo', :as => 'update_promo'
```

The controller action is:

```
def update_promo
  @property = Property.find(params[:id])

  if @property.update(property_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  else
    render 'edit'
  end   
end
```

The problem is that it's still calling the default Update action. And I get the error:

```
Couldn't find Property with 'id'=update_promo
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Full routes...

```
 get 'users/index'
  get 'home/index'

  get 'properties/update_regions', :as => 'update_regions'
  get 'properties/update_places', :as => 'update_places'
  get 'properties/update_map', :as => 'update_map'
  get 'properties/update_promo', :as => 'update_promo'

  root 'home#index'

  post "versions/:id/revert" => "versions#revert", :as => "revert_version"

  resources :properties

  resources :users do 
    collection do
      get :properties  # add this line 
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Could you post more of your routes file? It looks like the problem is the ordering of the routes but it would help to see.

Comment: Thanks Dave, added above.

Comment: try `:action => update_promo_path` I'm not sure this will work, that's why posting it in comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your routes.rb file's line:

```
get 'properties/update_promo', :as => 'update_promo'
```

to this:

```
post 'properties/update_promo', :as => 'update_promo'
```

Also, you can change your form to look like this:

```
= form_for( @property, :html => {:data => {:abide => ''}, :id  => 'property-edit-form'},:url => update_promo_path)) do |f|
```

You can use the url helpers instead of `url_for(:action => ...)`.

Comment: You're welcome buddy! Also, please try to use url helpers more than `:action => ..` cause you can change helper names to whatever at one place, but if you change action name then you'll have to update it everywhere in your code base. Caveat. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably GET methoding the submit so the show method is being called with the id update_promo, try adding

```
:method => :post
```

to the form_for.

To check, look at the log when you submit,
if your log starts with

```
Started GET
```

and not

```
Started POST
```

you need to add said paramter to form_for